# How to Convert Oracle 10G forms to Oracle apex 23.1?

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-23

We are currently using Oracle Forms and Reports in our premises. We are planning on migrating all the forms and reports to Oracle Apex. It is not a easy process to develop one by one in oracle apex 23.1.

So we are looking for a way to convert the 10G forms and Reports to Oracle Apex 23.1.

I tried to do it manually but its hard to convert all the validations and program units according to Oracle Apex.